# Using AssemblyName from MSBuild commandline causes error

Tags: c#, msbuild

Does anyone know why passing in AssemblyName as an MSBuild parameter causes an error?

```
& MSBuild -m $solutionFile /p:Configuration=$buildConfigName /t:publish /p:AssemblyName=$assemblyName;PublishDir="$publishPath\\"
```

This will cause a warning:

```
"warning BC40057: Namespace or type specified in the project-level Imports 'MyForms' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found."
```

My main assembly is referencing the MyForms assembly and it absolutely has lots of public members and classes.  Later in the build I get an error saying a type (that is in the MyForms assembly AND is public) is not defined:

```
error BC30002: Type 'InvokedArgs' is not defined.
```

However if I remove this commandline parameter and add the assemblyName directly into the project file under the build configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Acc|AnyCPU'">
    <AssemblyName>myApp_Acc</AssemblyName>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Acc\</OutputPath>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <InstallUrl>\\NetworkPath\ClickOnce\myApp\Acc\</InstallUrl>
    <ProductName>myApp %28Acc%29</ProductName>
    <DefineConstants>Win32 = True, VS2005 = True</DefineConstants>
    <BaseAddress>295212672</BaseAddress>
    <DocumentationFile>myApp.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <WarningLevel>1</WarningLevel>
    <NoWarn>41999,42016,42017,42018,42019,42020,42021,42022,42032,42036</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works without issue.  However due to some automated build needs, I need to specify the AssemblyName from the command line.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: The assembly name should be specified only for a single project.  Forcing it to be the same for all projects in a solution is bound to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for some inscrutable reason Microsoft decided to make the AssemblyName parameter sort of useless by default.  Not sure on what planet it makes sense to name all the assemblies in a solution with the same name, but that is the default behavior of that parameter.

To get this to work as it should (in my opinion) you need to add something like this to each build configuration that you want to customize the name of:

```
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(MSBuildAssemblyName)' == '' ">My_Default_Assembly_Name</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition=" '$(MSBuildAssemblyName)' != '' ">$(MSBuildAssemblyName)</AssemblyName>
```

The default is there for when you build from Visual Studio.
Then when you build from command line, use:

```
Set-Alias -Name MSBuild -Value "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

$buildParams = "/p:MSBuildAssemblyName=$assemblyName;PublishDir=`"$publishPath\\`""
& MSBuild -m $solutionFile /p:Configuration=$buildConfigName /t:publish $buildParams  | Out-Default
```